# how to compare my input text using jquery as validatidation for next step process

Tags: php, jquery

I have following code:
But, it still not working as i need to.,

```
function formValidation(e){
    var username = $('#username').val();

    $.post("check_username.php", { username: username },
        function(result){
            if(result == 0){
                jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Nama tidak cocok !</span>');
                return false;
            }else{
                jQuery('.fs-error').hide();
            }
    });
} else if {
    var tgllahir = $('#tgllahir').val();

    $.post("check_tgllahir.php", { tgllahir: tgllahir },
        function(result){
            if(result == 0){
                jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Tanggal Lahir tidak cocok !</span>');
                return false;
            }else{
                jQuery('.fs-error').hide();
            }
    });
}
```

This is not working.
getting nowhere when i click next button.
please any help.

Comment: Check your jquery version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to using jquery promise,until your request will done after that check result for validation.

```
function formValidation(e) {
var username = $('#username').val();

$.post("check_username.php", {
    username: username
}).done(function(result) {
    if (result == 0) {
        jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Nama tidak cocok !</span>');
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery('.fs-error').hide();
    }
});
var tgllahir = $('#tgllahir').val();
$.post("check_tgllahir.php", {
    tgllahir: tgllahir
}).done(function(result) {
    if (result == 0) {
        jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Tanggal Lahir tidak cocok !</span>');
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery('.fs-error').hide();
    }
});;
}
```